# Recalling viewDidLoad after failed connection not working

Tags: iphone, ios, viewdidload

this is my viewDidLoad function working well :

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    //iAds code
    adview = [[ADBannerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
    adview.frame = CGRectOffset(adview.frame, 0, 0);

    adview.requiredContentSizeIdentifiers = [NSSet setWithObject:ADBannerContentSizeIdentifierPortrait];
    adview.currentContentSizeIdentifier = ADBannerContentSizeIdentifierPortrait;
    [self.view addSubview:adview];
    adview.delegate = self;
    self.adbanerinvesiable = NO;

    //php data code
    NSError *er;
    SBJsonParser *parser = [[SBJsonParser alloc] init];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://localhost:8888/newjson.php?number=1"]];
    NSData *response = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];
    if (response.length != 0){
        NSString *json_string = [[NSString alloc]initWithData:response encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        listt = [parser objectWithString:json_string error:&er];
    }
    else {
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error" message:@"No Internet conniction" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:@"Refresh", nil];
        [alert show];

        //for ID contet post 
        SBJsonParser *parser2 = [[SBJsonParser alloc] init];
        NSURLRequest *request2 = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://localhost:8888/newjson.php?number=2"]];
        NSData *response2 = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request2 returningResponse:nil error:nil];
        NSString *json_string2 = [[NSString alloc]initWithData:response2 encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        IDNum = [parser2 objectWithString:json_string2 error:&er];
    }
}
```

As you can see if the connection failed it will show UIAlertView and two Buttons {ok , Refresh}.

I used this Method in case the refresh button been clicked to call viewDidLoad But not Working and giving me blank white view:

```
-(void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex{

    if (buttonIndex == 1){
        [self viewDidLoad];
    }
}
```

Any idea please ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should put your `PHP Data Code` in a method in it's own, so when you need to call that specifically you can, because you can't (or should I say **shouldn't**) call `viewDidLoad` manually. That should only be called automatically by `UIViewController`.

### Example

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    //iAds code
    adview = [[ADBannerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
    adview.frame = CGRectOffset(adview.frame, 0, 0);

    adview.requiredContentSizeIdentifiers = [NSSet setWithObject:ADBannerContentSizeIdentifierPortrait];
    adview.currentContentSizeIdentifier = ADBannerContentSizeIdentifierPortrait;
    [self.view addSubview:adview];
    adview.delegate = self;
    self.adbanerinvesiable = NO;
}

-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated    /* or: -(void)viewDidAppear: */
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animtaed];

    [self refreshPHData];
}

-(void)refreshPHPData
{
    //php data code
    NSError *er;
    SBJsonParser *parser = [[SBJsonParser alloc] init];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://localhost:8888/newjson.php?number=1"]];
    NSData *response = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];
    if (response.length != 0){
        NSString *json_string = [[NSString alloc]initWithData:response encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        listt = [parser objectWithString:json_string error:&er];
    }
    else {
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error" message:@"No Internet conniction" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:@"Refresh", nil];
        [alert show];

        //for ID contet post 
        SBJsonParser *parser2 = [[SBJsonParser alloc] init];
        NSURLRequest *request2 = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://localhost:8888/newjson.php?number=2"]];
        NSData *response2 = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request2 returningResponse:nil error:nil];
        NSString *json_string2 = [[NSString alloc]initWithData:response2 encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        IDNum = [parser2 objectWithString:json_string2 error:&er];
    }
}
```

Also, when you call `viewDidLoad` from your `UIAlertView`, you are creating a second (and third and so forth) **`adview`** because you aren't removing the previous instance. Depending on how many times the alert is shown and `viewDidLoad` is called, you are going to see adview stacking on top of itself. So try instead:

```
-(void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex{

    if (buttonIndex == 1){
        [self refreshPHPData];
    }
}
```

Comment: also it asking to download data each move, and that's consume a lot of phone data and make the app slower

Comment: Explain more on what is "not working". What does this code do for you, what does it not do for you?

Comment: Its basically the same affect that you originally have, only you are not recreating `adview` every time the user chooses **Refresh**. By calling `viewDidLoad` from the alert, you are still downloading the data.

Comment: Then in refreshPHPData, you need to refresh the tableView. add `[tableView reloadData];` **Just to note though, you make no mention of a table in your question.**

Comment: ok , but I am using UIViewController and when type [tableView reloadData]; it is giving me error .

Comment: You need to replace **tableView** with the instance name of YOUR table view. For example `myTable`.